# Find element with multiple classes selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to find an element with multiple classes per xpathusing Selenium Python. I tried something like this:

```
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='sqdOP.L3NKy.y3zKF']")
```

Here the HTML:

```
<button class="sqdOP  L3NKy   y3zKF     " disabled="" type="submit"><div class="                     Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         _4EzTm                                                                                                              ">Anmelden</div></button>
```

but it does not work. So how do I find these elements?

Comment: can you publish screen show with that element?seems like it generated dynamically. did it have dots or spaces?have you tried containes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're couples of ways how you can get the element:

```
driver_find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='sqdOP  L3NKy   y3zKF     ']")

driver_find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class,'sqdOP  L3NKy   y3zKF']")
    
driver_find_element_by_css_selector("button.sqdOP.L3NKy.y3zKF']")

driver_find_element_by_css_selector("sqdOP  L3NKy   y3zKF     ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to separate class by space not point:

```
self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='sqdOP L3NKy y3zKF']")
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to find several elements with the same class, you can try this:
`self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name(class)`